# Get All Subwebs in a Site Collection for the current loged in user in FBA in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, getsubwebs

Want to know  how to get all the sub sites [ upto 'N'th level ] where the current logged in user belongs to , either he is a visitor or he is a member or owner of the sub site.

Comment: i tried this link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/97e61e64-4011-4305-8e3b-04713ecee075/sharepoint-2013-get-list-of-all-sub-sites-in-which-the-logged-in-user-has-access-and-with-a?forum=sharepointsearch . but this is talkinga sbt search which i dont want

Comment: also i populated all the sub sites within a site collec and i showed to my customer. but they are not interested in ,they say thats not correct ,  he needs to see what all sub sites the end user has access, those sites needs to be shown in a grid or list.

Comment: SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser method will give me only the immediate subsite of the site collection and no at the N th level of site collec.